# Qt VirtualKeyboard enabling and disabling keys

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am writing an application that uses Qt 5.6.3 and QtVirtualKeyboard, and I need to be able to enable/disable its keys. I managed to do it by manually editing the layout files, but I need to do it dynamically, depending on user input.

I have `InputPanel` that I am using in my qml file like so

```
InputPanel {
    id: inputPanel
    visible: true
    y: parent.height - inputPanel.height
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
}
```

[image: Keyboard with all keys enabled]

This is the default keyboard with all keys enabled.

[image: QWERT disabled]

And here Q/W/E/R/T are disabled.

How can I disable VirtualKeyboard keys like that in either c++ or qml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this accepted answer ([Hide key from Qt Virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834050/hide-key-from-qt-virtual-keyboard)), I can propose this one which disables manually the 'm' key:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1
import "content"

Item {
    width: 1280
    height: 720

    property var keyboardLayout: inputPanel.keyboard.layout

    function disableKey(parent, objectText) {
        var obj = null
        if (parent === null)
            return null
        var children = parent.children
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            obj = children[i]
            if (obj.text === objectText && obj.toString().substring(0, 7) === "BaseKey") {
                obj.enabled = false
            }
            obj = disableKey(obj, objectText)
            if (obj)
                break
        }
        return obj
    }

    onKeyboardLayoutChanged: {
        if (keyboardLayout !== "") {
            disableKey(inputPanel.keyboard, 'm')
        }
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Kaldrr, could you help me? I want to know where did you add this code to enable language button? I have the same problem.

Comment: It seems these "BaseKeys" have a very limited set of properties. Perhaps I am mistaken but it would seem you can't change their color?